# modifying URL in wso2 esb

Tags: url-rewriting, wso2, esb, mediator

How can I add a static part in the query endpoint in WSO2 ESB service-proxy?
I created a pass through proxy to make an external api accessible via wso2 but the GET/POST query are sent to a link like this:

***http://host:port/services/service_name/car_name?op=CREATE&user=user1***

Is the a way to make the parameters part ( ?op=CREATE&user=user1 ) of the url did add automatically without being manually putted and the client just send a GET query to :

***http://host:port/services/service_name/car_name***

Comment: Do you want to send those query param to backend without getting them from the user?

Comment: yes but the client is using curl or postman/insomnia

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [REST_URL_POSTFIX](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/HTTP+Transport+Properties#HTTPTransportProperties-REST_URL_POSTFIXREST_URL_POSTFIX) property to add REST context pathes. This url is then added to the endpoint url.

```
<property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" value="/car_name?op=CREATE&user=user1" scope="axis2"/>
```

Second solution is to use the uri.var.* properties to be added to a [HTTP endpoint.](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/HTTP+Endpoint) See the example in the documentation:

```
<property name="uri.var.user" value="user1"/>
<property name="uri.var.servicename" value="PizzaWS"/>
<property name="uri.var.category" value="pizza"/>
<property name="uri.var.pizzaType" value="pan"/>
<send>
    <endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="HTTPEndpoint">
        <http uri-template="http://hot:port/services/service_name/car_name?op=CREATE&user={uri.var.user}" method="GET"/>
    </endpoint>
</send>
```

Which creates the following request:

```
http://hot:port/services/service_name/car_name?op=CREATE&user=user1
```